# How to use a function for a simultaneously run process in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

function func_name {
do something
}

find . -name "*" -type d -exec bash -c '( cd {} &&

func_name;

)' bash $1 $2 {} \;
```

$1 and $2 are commandline arguments unrelated to the question asked I believe. I am trying to go to all sub-directories and run a function, 
but I get a message "func_name: command not found"

Comment: did you try `export -f func_name` right after the function definition? it looks like you're running your function within a sub-shell

Comment: @PatrickTrentin You should post the answer as an *answer*. If it's only posted as a *comment*, the OP can't accept it, you won't get the reputation from upvotes and the question stays in the *unanswered* category.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan I apologize, sometimes solutions are so trivial that it makes me feel ashamed to post a full answer :)

Comment: @PatrickTrentin No worries. Sometimes the answer *is* that short and I would have felt much worse posting the answer when you'd already posted it first as a comment. Anyhow, here's an upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `func_name` is invoked within a sub-shell with a totally new environment, thus you should **export** it first:

```
#!/bin/bash

function func_name {
do something
}

export -f func_name

find . -name "*" -type d -exec bash -c '( cd {} &&

func_name;

)' bash $1 $2 {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you, I am just a beginner :)

Comment: You're welcome! No worries, we are all beginners, in some ways.